# How to compare 2 strings in cli (in one line)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

Wanted to evaluate things like following quickly

```bash
"84fbe59c20f52b43125f76a9101e373f775a75b89435cdda301a63694c69c2da" == "84fbe59c20f52b43125f76a9101e373f775a75b89435cdda30
1a63694c69c2da" // extected to get something like true or 1
```

How to do that in one line? Don't want to create a file to check that.
Seen that stack-overflow has many Q&A similar to this but all of those works with a file where my intention is to check this out quickly & without any file creation.

Comment: You mean `if [ '84fbe59c20f52b43125f76a9101e373f775a75b89435cdda301a63694c69c2da' = '84fbe59c20f52b43125f76a9101e373f775a75b89435cdda301a63694c69c2da' ]; then echo '1'; else; echo '0'; fi` ?

Comment: Your question is a bit blurry. In your concrete case of these specific literal strings, it is simply `[[ 84fbe59c20f52b43125f76a9101e373f775a75b89435cdda301a63694c69c2da != 84fbe59c20f52b43125f76a9101e373f775a75b89435cdda301a63694c69c2da ]]; echo $?`, which prints `1`. But in a realistic case you will have the strings stored in a file or in a variable, or the may contain other characters than hex digits; so this simplistic approach will not necessarily help you.

Comment: @Larme yes, btw I think the semicolon (`;`) should be removed which is after `else`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tested this in Git Bash and all good

```
[ "84fbe59c20f52b43125f76a9101e373f775a75b89435cdda301a63694c69c2da" == "84fbe59c20f52b43125f76a9101e373f775a75b89435cdda301a63694c69c2da" ] && echo "true" || echo "false"
```